# Specifying Custom Date Formats using Resharper

Tags: .net, resharper

I believe that there should be some awesome feature that will help me create custom date time formats inside my .ToString() method but I cant find the name of the feature or how to invoke it.

I found Formatting Specifier Completion in an old resharper blog but not sure if the feature has changed its name...

This is the version of Resharper I'm using: JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2016.1.2 Build 105.0.20160522.80219 ReSharper 2016.1.20160523.141907.

DevExpress has a cool one https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CodeRush/CustomDocument10844

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this was due to the fact that I was using Visual Studio intellisense instead of Resharper Intellisense